# ResultSet.update(..) vs st.executeUpdate(sql)

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Is it better to use `ResultSet.update` method or directly `st.executeUpdate(sql)` in order to update a database? Which one is better than the other and why?
Are these 2 methods totally interchangeable? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resultset.update requires a special kind of ResultSet, created like this:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(...);
```

Not all database support updateable result sets of this kind. The second option, however, may be safely used on any RDBMS as it's widely supported.